# sharing RSA keys between the server and the client

Tags: encryption, server, client, rsa

so im working on an application where the client encrypt the data with RSA (java) and send it to the server(php)  where the decryption must be done !
so the problem is how can i share the keys between the client and the server ?
just for information the client is sending the encrypted data by using the method GET so i can t send the key with the encrypted data because in this case everyone can see it and decrypt the information
so any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this, is for the client to initiate the connection. You would generate a key pair on the server and (securely) send the public key to the client. Then the client can encrypt a symmetric session key with the public key and send it to the server. Now, the server can decrypt the received packet and recover the session key (for example AES).

The problem is of course, to get the public key to the client securely. If you can embed the public key in the client code, then this is sort of ok, but if not, then this is vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack.

**Instead of rolling your own crypto, you really should be using established protocols such as TLS, because there is much that can go wrong.**

The above protocol is simplistic and doesn't achieve perfect forward secrecy. If you want that, then you would need to run a key agreement protocol on top of that for example with Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange.

Comment: thank you for answering ! the problem here is that im not good enough to do this alone i need to learn about it  so if i dont find something less complicated i ll learn what u asked me to try and thank you again for answering.

Comment: You can do this as a learning experience, but I strongly advise against doing this for any kind of production system considering that you're a novice in the field. It's probably better to use TLS with certificate pinning and there should be many tutorials around how this could be done with self-signed or CA signed certificates.

Comment: i really want to learn about it

Comment: Java provides all you need, but in PHP you will need phpseclib. The pain-points will not be the requests, but rather the different encodings.